# Display an ALAsset using QLPreviewController

Tags: ios, alasset, qlpreviewcontroller

I'm wanting to use QLPreviewController  to display ALAssets from the Photo Stream
QLPreviewController needs an NSURL to display the item

This works great when it is a File URL such as
/var/mobile/Applications/5374......9E0/Documents/image33.png

I have the ALAsset
However using  [[asset defaultRepresentation] url]  gives me a  NSURL type
assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000075&ext=JPG

But this does not display  QLPreviewController  just keeps showing loading ??

Any ideas ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe not the fastest and most efficient way, but it solves the problem. Please use NSFilemanager instead  NSTemporaryDirectory as in documentation :-) Make sure to link against ImageIO.framework

```
    #import <ImageIO/ImageIO.h>

    ....
    NSURL *outURLToUseWithQLPreviewController = nil;

    ALAsset *myAsset = ... // received somehow
    ALAssetRepresentation *represent = myAsset.defaultRepresentation;
    CGImageRef representFullScreen = represent.fullScreenImage;

    NSString *tempDir = NSTemporaryDirectory();
    NSString *imagePath = [tempDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:represent.filename];
    NSURL *tempURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:imagePath];

    CGImageDestinationRef destination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)(tempURL), (__bridge CFStringRef)(represent.UTI), 1, NULL);
    CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, representFullScreen, nil);
    if ( CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination) ) {
        outURLToUseWithQLPreviewController = tempURL;
    }
    return outURLToUseWithQLPreviewController;
```